# Column Name or number of supplied values does not match table definition (table definition is identical with what has been supplied)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have taken into account all your suggestions and amended the code however I am still getting the same error even though I have checked the query and the table definition all morning long. What are your views on this?

```
CREATE TABLE #tempNonInvoicedExportResults
        (
          DateCreated DATE ,
          DestinationCountry CHAR(2) , 
          DestinationDepot CHAR(3) , 
          MovementRef CHAR(12) ,
          TotalCons INT ,
          SailingDate DATETIME ,
          TrailerNumber VARCHAR(50) ,
          TotalEstimatedChargeableWeight DECIMAL NULL ,
          PayableInUK BIT NULL ,
          HasLongLengthConsignments BIT ,
      CountOfConsOnMovement VARCHAR (100)

        )

         INSERT INTO #tempNonInvoicedExportResults
            SELECT  
                   CAST(CON.[Date Loaded] AS DATE) as DateCreated,
                  ISNULL(STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '/' + COALESCE(cr2.DestinationCountry, 'NA')
                   FROM     movMovement mov2
                            INNER JOIN movConLink mcl2 ON mcl2.MovementID = mov2.MovementID
                            INNER JOIN cgtRoute cr2 ON cr2.RouteID = mcl2.CMRRouteID
                   WHERE    cr2.DestinationCountry <> 'GB'
                            AND cr2.RouteID = mcl2.CMRRouteID
                            AND mov2.MovementID = MM.MovementID
                   FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS DestinationCountry,
                   ISNULL(STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '/' + COALESCE(cr2.DestinationDepot, 'NA')
                   FROM     movMovement mov2
                            INNER JOIN movConLink mcl2 ON mcl2.MovementID = mov2.MovementID
                            INNER JOIN cgtRoute cr2 ON cr2.RouteID = mcl2.CMRRouteID
                   WHERE    cr2.DestinationCountry <> 'GB'
                            AND cr2.RouteID = mcl2.CMRRouteID
                            AND mov2.MovementID = MM.MovementID
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS DestinationDepot, 
                    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
                           REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', '')) > 0
                           THEN STUFF(STUFF(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', ''),
                                        PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
                                                 REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', '')), 10), 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-') ELSE MM.MovementRef END AS MovementRef, 
                    COUNT(MCL.ConsignmentReference) AS TotalCons,
                    MM.SailingDateTime as SailingDate, 
                    MU.Number as TrailerNumber, 
                    SUM(EstimatedChargeableWeight) as TotalEstimatedChargeableWeight, 
                    UKPayable as PayableInUK, 
                    tl.HasLongLengthConsignments as HasLongLengthConsignments, 
                    CASE WHEN COUNT(MCL.ConsignmentReference) < 3 THEN 'Movement has 3 or less cons' ELSE 'Movement has 3 or more cons' END AS CountOfConsOnMovement
```

Comment: Hard to guess without knowing result of your inner query. Better run your `Select` statement and check the result.

Comment: The select statement is incomplete.  Where are you getting MovementRef, TotalCons, SailingDate, TrailerNumber, TotalEstimatedChargeableWeight, PayableInUK, HasLonglengthConsignments?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong, but you could try select into instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do `SELECT INTO` a permanent table dbo.tmp like this (add your from clause):

```
        SELECT  
               CAST(CON.[Date Loaded] AS DATE) as DateCreated, /*1*/

              ISNULL(STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '/' + COALESCE(cr2.DestinationCountry, 'NA')
               FROM     movMovement mov2
                        INNER JOIN movConLink mcl2 ON mcl2.MovementID = mov2.MovementID
                        INNER JOIN cgtRoute cr2 ON cr2.RouteID = mcl2.CMRRouteID
               WHERE    cr2.DestinationCountry <> 'GB'
                        AND cr2.RouteID = mcl2.CMRRouteID
                        AND mov2.MovementID = MM.MovementID
               FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS DestinationCountry, /*2*/

               ISNULL(STUFF(( SELECT DISTINCT '/' + COALESCE(cr2.DestinationDepot, 'NA')
               FROM     movMovement mov2
                        INNER JOIN movConLink mcl2 ON mcl2.MovementID = mov2.MovementID
                        INNER JOIN cgtRoute cr2 ON cr2.RouteID = mcl2.CMRRouteID
               WHERE    cr2.DestinationCountry <> 'GB'
                        AND cr2.RouteID = mcl2.CMRRouteID
                        AND mov2.MovementID = MM.MovementID
             FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '') AS DestinationDepot, /*3*/

                CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
                       REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', '')) > 0
                       THEN STUFF(STUFF(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', ''),
                                    PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',
                                             REPLACE(MU.Number, '-', '')), 10), 3, 0, '-'), 6, 0, '-') ELSE MM.MovementRef END AS MovementRef, /*4*/

                COUNT(MCL.ConsignmentReference) AS TotalCons, /*5*/

                MM.SailingDateTime as SailingDate,  /*6*/

                MU.Number as TrailerNumber, /*7*/

                SUM(EstimatedChargeableWeight) as TotalEstimatedChargeableWeight, /*8*/

                UKPayable as PayableInUK, /*9*/

                tl.HasLongLengthConsignments as HasLongLengthConsignments, /*10*/

                CASE WHEN COUNT(MCL.ConsignmentReference) < 3 THEN 'Movement has 3 or less cons' ELSE 'Movement has 3 or more cons' END AS CountOfConsOnMovement /*11*/
    into dbo.tmp
    from ...
```

Once you have created dbo.tmp, find it in Management Studio and Script it as `CREATE`

In the generated script change dbo.tmp to #tempNonInvoicedExportResults

Comment: This syntax is ok. Also if you would create a table with a column with no name and no datatype, you will get another error.

Comment: I'm not saying that the table creation is wrong. I said, the table has more fields, not all of them we see in the original post

Comment: Indeed, I have identified an extra field in the select stated and added it into the create table statement as a field on its own. However, I am still getting the same error even though I have thoroughly checked the query now.

Comment: @sepupic The table has 10 columns and we can see them all. The comma at the end doesn't change anything. Try "CREATE TABLE #test ( id int,) insert into #test select 1 drop table  #test"

Comment: Instead of counting fields, do SELECT..INSERT into a permanent table, then script it as CREATE and copy-paste the definition changing it to temporary table

Comment: @Peter, the server does not say wrong things, the column number is different. And it's bad to INSERT into without writing all the fields of insert like this: INSERT INTO tab (field1, field2,...)

Comment: @sepupic You are making point sepupic. I have correct the mistake you pointed me out to but the same error is outstanding. What should be the cause of it?

Comment: @Peter, sepupic was making a valid point and I have correct that issue, however, I am still getting the same error even though the table definition matches all my fields in the select statement (number wise but also column names). What is the cause of this?

Comment: You should list all the fields you insert in the parenthesis

Comment: ...And why don't you just do SELECT (all your code) INTO dbo.tmp, to see the table created and to script its structure without errors?

Comment: CountOfConsOnMovement was added after edit? There is no such a field in the table above...

Comment: @sepupic, yes, CountOfConsOnMovement was added and I forgot to add it in the edit. When I execute it, it is there. Can you please detailed your previous answer regarding dbo.tmp ?